# Как программно изменить уровень View-элемента в иерархии элементов

Tags: java, android, xml

Как программно изменить порядок отображения View элементов, то есть есть два элемент View1 и View2, если в разметке xml сначала идёт View1,а затем View2, то View2 перекроет собой View1, как программно можно изменять их уровень ?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/q/4182486/3212712

Answer (score 1):

Изменить программно `xml`-разметку нельзя. Попробуйте скрывать/показывать `View` в зависимости от необходимости.

К примеру.

```
editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);//скрываем
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//показываем
```

Либо смотреть в сторону динамического создания элементов во время выполнения приложения. Там расположение зависит только от вашей фантазии.

Comment: я вас понял спасибо!